# How to install opencv in ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, ubuntu-11.10

I have been searching all over the net and doing what is being said.How should I install open cv in ubuntu 11.10 platform? I want to do some image processing using open cv. Thanks. Btw, Im a novice in programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- download latest OpenCV-2.4.2.tar.bz2 and extract it.
- in terminal `cd` to the Opencv-2.4.2
- run `mkdir release`
- cd release
- run `cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D BUILD_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON ..`
- run `sudo make install`

That's it to install opencv. It will take almost 30 mins to install.

But after successful installation you might get another issue with your Ubuntu 11.10 (in my experience). You may get linking error with opencv libraries. To get rid of that problem run `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib` on every login session. Or add `/usr/local/lib` -this line at end of `/etc/ld.so.conf` for a permanent solution.

You can download my detailed opencv implementation of histogram equalization from my website for a good start-up!

my [website](http://www.cse.iitd.ac.in/~mcs112580) :